# how to convert hexadecimal value to blob in iphone

Tags: iphone

in my application i have an image which is of hexadecimal type;
i want to convert in to blob type and save to database;

how it is possible.

Regards
K L BAIJU

Comment: What do you mean with hexadecimal type? is it base64 encoded?

Answer (score 0):

according to my knowledge it is base64 encoded, suppose if you got image data from web service you need to encode the received string data into base64 encoding.

```
NSData* data=[[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64ImageString];
```

then you can easily retrieved data into UIImageView,

```
UIImageView* imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
```

and to save the image data into sqlite as Blob data-type used following snippet

```
if(insertStmt == nil) {
   const char *sql = "insert into TableName values(?,?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insertStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
       NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 1, [imageName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);

int returnValue = -1;

returnValue = sqlite3_bind_blob(insertStmt, 2, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], NULL);

if(returnValue != SQLITE_OK)
   NSLog(@"Not OK!!!");

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(insertStmt))
   NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

sqlite3_reset(insertStmt);

[data release];
[imageView release];
```

to retrieved image data from database

```
if(detailStmt == nil) {
 const char *sql = "Select * from TableName";
  if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &detailStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating detail view statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
 }

 if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(detailStmt)) {
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(detailStmt, 2) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(detailStmt, 2)];

  if(data == nil)
     NSLog(@"No image found.");
  else
    imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];        
 }
```

regards,
Mayur